How can i write to a specific cell in a Google sheets range?
I am creating a discord bot and would like to write to a specific cell in Google sheets. With this code i am able to post the userInput into the embed when the command is executed on discord.
However the code is returning an error : Missing range, and is not writing in google sheets.
Essentially i want the user to use the command "/checkbl steamidhere". "steamidhere" would be whatever the userInput is. Write that user input into the Google sheets cell H1.
This is my code I am currently using:
async sample() {
    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth });
    const spreadsheetId = "sheetid";
  
    const sheetName = "BOTDATA";
    const cells = ["H1"];
    const valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED";
    const userInput = "sample value";
  
    const result = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
      spreadsheetId,
      range: `'${sheetName}'!${cells[0]}`,
      resource: { values: [[userInput]] },
      valueInputOption,
    });
    console.log(result.data);
  }
  
  sample();


I believe your goal is as follows.

You want to put a value userInput of const userInput = interaction.options.get('steamid').value; into the cell "H1" of "BOTDATA" sheet.

In this case, how about the following modification? In this modification, the function readBlacklist() is not used. Only the value userInput is put into the cell "H1" of "BOTDATA" sheet.
Modified script:
From:
const userInput = interaction.options.get('steamid').value;
const bl = new EmbedBuilder()

To:
const userInput = interaction.options.get('steamid').value;

// --- I added the below script.
const spreadsheetId = "myspreadsheetID";
const sheetName = "BOTDATA";
const cells = ["H1"];
const valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED";
// const userInput = "sample value"; // This is a sample value. In your situation, "const userInput = interaction.options.get('steamid').value;" is used.
const result = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
  spreadsheetId,
  range: `'${sheetName}'!${cells[0]}`,
  resource: { values: [[userInput]] },
  valueInputOption,
});
// console.log(result.data); // If you want to confirn the returned value, please use this.
// ---

const bl = new EmbedBuilder()


When this script is run and your other parts work fine, the value userInput is put into the cell "H1" of "BOTDATA" sheet.

Note:

In this modification, it supposes that your client sheets can be used for putting the values to the Spreadsheet using Sheets API. Please be careful about this.

Reference:

Method: spreadsheets.values.update

Added:
From your following reply,

I've updated my original question with the modification, and the error i am receiving.

and, the following your new error,

Unfortunately i am getting TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function

Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your new error. I'm worried whether your new error is related to my script. So, in order to check it, please test the following script. In the additional script, only my script is used. If the same error occurs, please tell me.
async function sample() { // <--- Modified
  const sheets =   // Please use your client
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your spreadsheet ID.

  const sheetName = "BOTDATA";
  const cells = ["H1"];
  const valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED";
  const userInput = "sample value";

  // const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth }); // Please remove this line.
  const result = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
    spreadsheetId,
    range: `'${sheetName}'!${cells[0]}`,
    resource: { values: [[userInput]] },
    valueInputOption,
  });
  console.log(result.data);
}

sample();


I've updated my original question with the modification, and the error i am receiving.

@famq Thank you for replying. About your new error of TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function, unfortunately, it seems that my modified script doesn't use intermediate value. I'm worried whether your new error is related to my script. So, in order to check it, please test the additional script. In the additional script, only my script is used. If the same error occurs, please tell me.

@famq By the way, in your updated script, please remove const write = await readBlacklist(['test']); and console.log(write);. In my modification, readBlacklist is not used as mentioned in my answer. Beucase your readBlacklist is not correct. Please be careful about this.

Okay sorry about that, Ive removed const write = await readBlacklist(['test']) and console.log(write); and it was still giving an error, Ive removed all my code and replaced it with your "Added" code and am getting this error cannot redeclare blocked-scoped variable 'sheets'

@famq I have to apologize for my very very poor skill. I noticed that in my added script, I forgot to remove my used cliend const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth });. Your new error cannot redeclare blocked-scoped variable 'sheets' is due to this.  So, please remove it. The reason that I forgot to remove it is due to my very very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my very very poor skill again.

with this new script i have only your script here and am seeing 2 errors:
Unexpected keyword or identifier.
and
';' expected.
One is for async and the other for the "{" at the end of it

@famq Thank you for replying. First, when I tested my added script, no error occurred. About with this new script i have only your script here and am seeing 2 errors: Unexpected keyword or identifier. and ';' expected. One is for async and the other for the "{" at the end of it, in this case, I think that this is due to your actual script. I'm worried that you might not correctly copy and paste my script. So, please confirm it again. If you cannot understand it, please provide your current script so that it can be replicated correctly.

Ive gone ahead and replaced my entire index.js file into my original question post. My question is related to line 244 - CHECKBL COMMAND

@famq Thank you for replying. About Ive gone ahead and replaced my entire index.js file into my original question post. My question is related to line 244 - CHECKBL COMMAND, when I saw your showing script, I'm worried that your added script is large script. My added script is very simple. In order to simply test, I would like to recommend testing only my added script including your client without other parts. By the way, when I tested only your showing sample() with valid client, no error occurs. So, I'm worried that your other parts might be the reason for your current issue.

Ive created a new js file. and am still recieving the same two errors.

@famq Now, I noticed that you updated your question. In your script, how about modifying async sample() { to async function sample() {?

Okay, I am sorry about that, in one of your previous modifications it was scripted like that, But i have corrected it and it works! Thank you so much! It works now!

@famq Thank you for repying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Sorry again,  I am getting the "sample value" response into my H1 cell in my Google sheet,  How would i replace this with what the user typed?
EDIT:
Ive replaced userInput variable with what i want to use and it works! Sorry about that, again thanks for the help!

So If i wanted to read "H2" and write to "H1" Would i need to create 2 different async functions to do so? Sorry for asking so many questions i just want to make sure i understand this correctly.

Ive actually come across an issue, When i change userInput to interaction.options.get('steamid').value; it works, but all my other commands do not work, im assuming because the input is coming from the async command, and i cannot edit a function? Can you please help me with this if possible.

@famq About your new question Ive actually come across an issue, When i change userInput to interaction.options.get('steamid').value; it works, but all my other commands do not work, im assuming because the input is coming from the async command, and i cannot edit a function? Can you please help me with this if possible., I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Just posted it, thanks again.
